# AS3 Getting which movieclip clicked on

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

So, I made a for loop to get several buttons in my project. It's a questionary, and I need to have a button to quickly select and navigate to any question there. I could do them all manually, but not only would my code be long and confusing, but also there are problems since there isn't always the same number of questions.

So right now I have:

```
function SetQuestionSquares():void{
    for(var i:Number = 1; i <= TestProperties.QuestionLimit;i++){
        var QuestionSquare:questionsquare = new questionsquare;
        QuestionSquare.buttonMode = true;
        QuestionSquare.mouseChildren = false;
        QuestionSquare.x = NavLeft.x + (20 * i);
        QuestionSquare.y = NavLeft.y;
        QuestionSquare.questionsquaretext.text = i.toString();
        addChild(QuestionSquare);
        QuestionSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GoToQuestionNumber);
    }
    addChild(NavLeft);
    addChild(NavRight);
}

function GoToQuestionNumber(e:MouseEvent):void{
    WhichQuestion = ???; //I don't know what goes here. 
    UpdateQuestions();
    trace("testing"); //Gets called correctly, so its working.
}
```

My problem is identifying which square was clicked. I need to have some way to grab the "e" (clicked) event, so I know which button the user clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [.target](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#target) property of the [Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html) object:

```
WhichQuestion = e.target as questionsquare;
```

Comment: That doesen't get me a unique identifier, from what I tested. They all come back as "questionsquare". I needed something like "QuestionSquare1". Do I need to do something in the "addChild" loop for them to get a unique identifier?

Comment: Okay, figured a solution out. Just did a "QuestionSquare.name = i.toString();" in the loop and then a "WhichQuestion = e.target.name;". Don't know it thats the most correct way to do it, but it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoFox Alternatively you can use [getChildIndex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildIndex()) -> `WhichQuestion = e.target.parent.getChildIndex(e.target)+1`

Comment: You should really use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`

Comment: @32bitkid Nope, you are wrong, see `QuestionSquare.mouseChildren = false;` in the OP's question.

Comment: That means `e.currentTarget` and `e.target` are set to the same instance, I would still say that `currentTarget`, as defined by the API, is the "right" property when referring to the object that is currently processing the event, not the one that raised the event.

Comment: @32bitkid As you said, in this case there is no difference, so the `.target` is an option too.P.S. I know the difference between those very well

Comment: I get, im not questioning you, nor saying its wrong. But it is a subtlety that can be mitigated. I'm not sure the op or someone else who finds this question will get the distinction. I would be explicit, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GoToQuestionNumber(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var WhichQuestion:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
    UpdateQuestions();
    trace("testing");
}
```